# UiITextView text is not deleting the text after tapping the delete button on the keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a UITextView called myTextView and a UILabel called charLabel.

I use the UITextView delegate methods to update the label to count the char that are left (35 and down).

The bug - after im writing text in the textview and the label gets to 0, I cant delete the text..., in any number I can, but only when I get to 0 im stuck..

This is my code:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

    self.charLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",35 - (unsigned long)textView.text.length];
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text1
{

    textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
    if(textView.text.length >= 35){
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }

}
```

Would love to get some help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in very simple way you may use [ReactiveCoca](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) and you can check [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62699/reactivecocoa-tutorial-pt1) tutorial about them. Its very powerful library.

If you want to go ahead in your case, below code may help you to figure out how to do that:

```
@implementation yourViewController
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        _textView.delegate = self;
    }
    - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
        [_textView setText:@""];
    }

    - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
        [_charLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)(35 - textView.text.length)]];
    }

    NSString *holderString = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

if(holderString.length > 35)
    return NO;
else
    return YES;
```

and **be sure** that you connected delegate to self for textView.

Can be an example to you how you may use in Reactive:

```
[[self.textView.rac_textSignal
  map:^id(NSString *text) {
      return @(text.length);
  }]
 subscribeNext:^(id x) {

     int xToInt = (int)x/16;

     if (xToInt > 0)  //this provide to keep the count stable when user do "select all and delete".
            [_charLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",35 - xToInt]];

     else
         [_counterLabel setText:@"35"];

     if (xToInt > 35)
            [_charLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
     else
         [_charLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:179/255.0 green:179/255.0 blue:179/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

 }];
```

Comment: thanks allot! but before I do that, is there a way to fix my current code...? its not a complicated task and it feels like there should be also a simple solution to this...there is a delegate method for uitextview that called textViewDidBeginEditing, but from some reason it dosen't work as well, any other solutions bro?

Comment: Sorry about wrong answer I edited that and the problem that i forgot to delegate textView to itself thats why i told you textViewDidChange delegate method only appears once to see you made change or not. It controls every change you made. So the second problem i didn't get the problem well and didn't realize that backspace does not work when you reach to 35 text length. In that case regarding of  Mike Gledhill answer, if you should define another string that can hold the text range you can handle whatever you want when you reached to end.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, **Rengers** is correct with his response.  You're denying any changes to the text (even if the user is attempting to *delete* characters) once you get to 35 characters.

I haven't tested this code, but what you should be doing is "calculating" what the new string will be, after the user has added/deleted his current character, and measuring the length of *that* string.

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text1
{
    NSString *newString = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text1];

    if(newString.length >= 35){
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, if the character count is 35 or more, any changes are denied because you return NO in the delegate method.

You should check here whether the user added a character or deletes a character and respond accordingly.

I'm not sure how from the top of my head but you should be able to figure this out by logging the variables inside the delegate method and pressing the delete button.